# Dynamic import on Angular 7+

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build project that contains some components with dynamic imports, like:

```js
import {Directive, Input, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[saKnob]'
})
export class KnobDirective {

  @Input() saKnob: any;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    import('jquery-knob').then(()=>{
      this.render()
    })
  }

  render(){
    $(this.el.nativeElement).knob(this.saKnob || {})
  }
}
```

The dynamic import on the constructor seems to be the problem. I'm getting the following error:

```sh
ERROR in ./src/app/shared/forms/input/knob.directive.ts 15:8
Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level 
(15:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         var _this = this;
|         this.el = el;
>         import('jquery-knob').then(function () {
|             _this.render();
|         });
```

As far as I researched, this kind of import is supported since Angular 4, and I'm using Angular 7.

Does anyone have an idea on what could be the problem?

*** UPDATE ***

As pointed by some answers, I was already using esnext on my `tsconfig.app.file` file:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "esnext",
    "types": [],
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

And here's the contents of the `tsconfig.json`

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "paths": {
    "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
    "@env/*": ["src/environments/*"]
    }
}
}
```

My typescript version is `~3.1.6`.

Comment: Open up `tsconfig.ts` and and use `esNext`.

Answer (score 6):

**In short:**

It's caused by [npm issue](https://npm.community/t/packages-with-peerdependencies-are-incorrectly-hoisted/4794) appeared with `@angular-devkit/build-angular` update from `0.12.x` to `0.13.x` and related webpack update under the hood from `4.28.x` to `4.29.x`.

**Possible solutions (workarounds):**

- use `@angular-devkit/build-angular` 0.12.x
- try workarounds mentioned [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8656#issuecomment-456713191). One working for me is to add explicit latest `acorn` dependency (e. g. `npm i --save acorn` will add `6.1.1` at the time of writing). Another popular workaround is to run `npm update acorn --depth 20 && npm dedupe`.
- use [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com) if applicable

**Details:**

Have recently stumbled upon similar issue after project update from Angular 7.2 to Angular 7.3. Before update build was fine, and `esnext` as `target` was already specified in `tsconfig.json`.

After some tests I've revealed that it relates to `@angular-devkit/build-angular` and found issues ([13767](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13767), [13793](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13793)) in angular-cli that surprisingly were closed.
But **alan-agius4** [comment in issue 13793](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13767#issuecomment-468250132) shed some light to real origin: invalid  hoisting for peer dependencies; explained in details by **sokra** [in this comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8656#issuecomment-456010969).

There were already accepted pull request #147 for issue #4794, but then it was [reverted in pull request #152](https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/152) and issue #4794 remains opened at the time of writing.

[dynamic-import](/questions/tagged/dynamic-import)

Comment: Great write-up, been working on this for two hours. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just call `import` like that. You need to import `SystemJS` first. then call its `import` method.

```js
import('jquery-knob').then(()=>{
  this.render()
})
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bkbqkj

Comment: With this, the code actually compiles, but I get the following warning: `System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.`

Comment: `import()` is completely valid. Have a look at `Dynamic Imports` section at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Answer (score 0):

It works when creating a new project using `ng new` with the latest angular-cli.

I think the problem is your Typescript config. Try to set these values in you `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
        "es2018",
        ...
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Angular 8. First install acorn (acorn will be added in package.json file) then delete node_modules & package-lock.json then npm install.

```
npm install acorn
rm -rf node_modules
rm -f package-lock.json
npm install
```