# 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level - brand new to angular

Tags: angular

Just starting out with Angular, downloaded an Angular/.NET-core template from https://aspnetboilerplate.com as well.

When attempting to compile the project (npm start) it fails with this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/root.module.ts 39:24
Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level 
(39:24)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|                     if (shouldLoadLocale()) { 
|                         var angularLocale = convertAbpLocaleToAngularLocale(abp.localization.currentLanguage.name);
>                         import("@angular/common/locales/" + angularLocale     + ".js")
|                             .then(function (module) {
|                             registerLocaleData(module.default);
```

Any suggestions on how i can resolve this issue? My searches through this site aren't really helping me with this specific issue.

Comment: Seems you just need to set module to `esnext` in tsconfig. [Source](https://netbasal.com/using-typescript-dynamic-imports-in-angular-d210547484dd)

Comment: @Phix thank you. looking at the tsconfig, module is currently set to "esnext". any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like duplicate of another question, please try workarounds from my answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128908/11192947

[dynamic-import](/questions/tagged/dynamic-import)